# Complicated Formula

Tags: excel

I'm really struggling to put together a formula for the following scenario:

```
If M3 is less than S3 then add O3 and P3 together,
If M3 and S3 are both empty then display '0',
If M3 is the exact same number as S3 then display add O3 and P3 together and then add '5',
If M3 is greater than S3 then display '20'
```

I've got the following so far:

```
=IF(AND(M3<S3),SUM(O3+P3),IF(AND(M3=S3),5+O3+P3,IF(AND(M3=S3),"0")))
```

But it's displaying `5` even when the cells are blank - any ideas?

Comment: The function `AND()` combines two or more conditions into a single expression. You should either strip it (it is useless now) or add more conditions where appropriate.

Comment: @chancea Maybe for the non-descriptive title? The question itself seems fine, albeit a little easy, could probably have figured out the answer with a little more research on nested IF statements.

Comment: @JoeMalpass I guess I glanced over the title at first, it is not very helpful or descriptive of the question (regardless whether or not someone actually considers this "complicated") so you make a valid point

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
=IF(LEN(M3) + LEN(S3) = 0, "0", IF(M3 < S3, O3 + P3, IF(M3 = S3, O3 + P3 + 5, 20)))
```

Comment: I like that you check if they are empty first instead of the difference

Comment: This is spot on - thanks for helping. I'm just starting to experiment with excel formulas and it's proving very complicated given what I'm trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(M3<S3,SUM(O3+P3),
    IF(AND(M3="",S3=""),0,
        IF(M3=S3,5+O3+P3,
            IF(M3>S3,20,"Other Criteria"
))))
```

I find it easier to use new lines for each.

The reason it was showing 5 is that your 2nd and 3rd 'if' were mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer to your question is:

`=IF(M3<S3,O3+P3,IF(AND(M3="",S3=""),0,IF(M3=S3,(O3+P3+5),IF(M3>S3,20,""))))`

That is going to cause you a boat load of errors though. There are to many conditions that are not accounted for.

What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a Cricket League Table but the points system I have to adhere to is very complicated.  
  
Essentially...  
  
**Win**  
  
20 points  
  
**Lose**  
  
0 points  
  
**Match Abandoned**  
  
5 points  
  
  
  
**Bonus Points**  
  
1 point per 25 runs scored over 75 (maximum of 5 points)  
  
e.g. 75 runs = 1pt, 100 runs = 2pts, 125 runs = 3pts, 150 runs = 4pts, 175 runs = 5pts  
  
1 point for every two wickets taken (again, maximum of 5 points)  
  
e.g. 2 wickets = 1pt, 4 wickets = 2pts, 6 wickets = 3pts, 8 wickets = 4pts, 10 wickets = 5pts

Comment: _N.B. In a complete game, bonus points can only be awarded to the LOSING side. However, in the event that the match is abandoned part way through, they can be awarded to both teams in addition to the match abandoned points._

So for example, if a match is abandoned with the Home Team being 250 for 10, and the away team being 175 for 2…

Home Team

5 points for abandonment + 5 batting points + 1 bowling point

TOTAL = 11 points

Away Team

5 points for abandonment + 4 batting points + 5 bowling points

TOTAL = 15 points

Comment: That's a whole lot of information that I really can't digest. I don't watch sports and really who is a winner or loser is up to the user to decide based on the gradients applied. I had an opportunity that required, and frankly I ended up using a db instead after I fought with it for 4 days, that required stacking over 20 if statements. As you can understand Excel only does 7 so I created it in what ultimately became 5 different cells comparing results of results of results. It was interesting. Best advice: Eliminate what you don't want first, then calculate

Comment: If you have a condition that will never occur, remove that from your results. Concentrate on those conditions that never occur and you'll be halfway home. Good Luck.